# variable not sent to controller upon form submission in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

The following is my return :

```
return redirect()->route('account', ['key' => 1]);
```

Next is the blade code trying to use the above key variable :

```
<input type = "key" name = "key"  id="key" value="{{$key}}">
```

The route :

```
Route::get('/account', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@getAccount',
    'as' => 'account'
]);
```

I'm not sure why the value of 1 is not being sent upon submitting the form.

Comment: Why you not using `return view('account', compact('key'))`

Comment: you are redirecting to a form and then submitting the form. when you are submitting the form you are not getting the variable value in controller. right?? are you sure you want a redirect or just to return to a view.

Comment: Can i know what is the difference between redirect and return ?

Comment: a redirect is a process where the application goes to the redirect route and then the controller action for the corresponding route while the return view just returns to a view page.

Comment: can you also provide the getAccount function here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
input type="key"
```

to

```
input type="hidden"
```

also, make the route like this:

```
Route::get('/account/{key}', [
'uses' => 'UserController@getAccount',
'as' => 'account'
]);
```

and it should work